# Counting using for loops within a list

Tags: python, loops

For this function, I have to count repeated items within a list. For instance, given the following list = [1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4] the output should be returned the number of different repeated values within that list, so the output would be 3

```
    while data < 15
    count = 1
    num = 1

    for i in range(len(data) - 1):
        if data[i] != data[i + 1]:
            num = num + 1

    return num
```

This is the input and output sample:

input: [4,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,8,7]
output: 6
Above is the code that I have written so far.

Comment: If we reverse-engineer the formula based on your two examples, it looks like you're looking for `max(data)-min(data)`. Otherwise, please add several more input and output example pairs because the output of 6 for the 2nd input example doesn't agree with the verbal requirements you specified

Answer (score 0):

You can do with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html),

```
from collections import Counter
print(Counter(lst).most_common()[0][1])
```

Counter will return a dictionary with values and counts

Execution:

```
In [1]: lst = [1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4]

In [2]: print(Counter(lst).most_common()[0][1])
3

In [3]: lst = [4,4,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,8,7]

In [4]: print(Counter(lst).most_common()[0][1])
35
```

Comment: the ouput should be 6, though.

Comment: @AngelsVásquez Can you please explain the logic here? I thought you looking for the maximum count.

Comment: well I guess the OP is asking for the number of distinct items in the list: e.g., [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3] has repeated 1, 2, 3 => 3

Comment: @luma Still that didn't match the second output.

Comment: @AngelsVásquez When I saw "6 Above" in your question, I thought value you looking for more than 6. My bad

Comment: Oh yeah just realise that it does not match the second sample... but I guess this is most likely the idea of the OP; @AngelsVásquez I guess you want to clarify the logic